# How to combine or modify S4 objects?

Tags: r, r-s4

I am struggling to find an easy way to modify S4 objects having many slots.  A toy example is:

```
setClass(
    Class = "First",
    slots = c(foo = "numeric")
)
setClass(
    Class = "Second",
    slots = c(bar = "numeric"),
    contains = "First"
)
dog <- new(Class="First",
           foo = 1)
cat <- new(Class="Second", 
           foo = dog@foo,
           bar = 1)
str(cat)
```

This is trivial because class First contains only one slot (foo).  Is there an easy way to combine/modify S4 objects which contain many slots?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to instantiate a sub-class with the values of a parent class instance.  I don't think there is an easy way to do this, but it can be done.  Here, we retrieve the parent class instance slot values, and use `do.call` to instantiate a child class object:

```
par.slots <- sapply(slotNames(dog), slot, object=dog, simplify=F)
do.call("new", c("Second", bar=1, par.slots))

## An object of class "Second"
## Slot "bar":
## [1] 1
## 
## Slot "foo":
## [1] 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, most people who create S4 objects create a variety of methods to work on them in the ways you would be most inclined manipulate data for your given purpose.

Sometimes that is by creating a whole new class-specific method to accomplish a specific task and others it is by creating a `do` that instructs R to apply the class-specific implementation of an existing generic function (such as `rbind` or `summary`) You can read about it here:

[Bioconductor S4 Tutorial](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2013/CSAMA2013/friday/afternoon/S4-tutorial.pdf)

This should get you headed in the right direction creating your own functions or customizing existing generics to work with your objects.